# Align currency to the right on format string

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I have a `DisplayFormat` in my C# code like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]
```

And the ouput is like: `USD 50`
But how can i change this display format to show: `50 USD`? with the currency symbol on the right?

Comment: You can create a custom NumberFormatInfo object with the appropriate value for CurrencyPositivePattern and CurrencyNegativePattern.  See, for example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This page lists all of the custom string formats available for currencies, there are plenty of links to other format string pages on msdn as well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Specifically, it looks like you want `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0C}")]`? That almost seems too simple, did you try that already?

--- Edit ---

Ok, figured that would be too simple. `C0` implies "print number (with `0` decimal places), then the currency (the `C`)". However, further down on that page are more specifics with the currency pattern. Buried in that is this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern(v=vs.110).aspx

- 0 results in $n
- 1 results in n$
- 2 results in $ n
- 3 results in n $

So you want either currency pattern 1 or 3. Now you need to find some way to put that in to the `DisplayFormat` attribute, hopefully there's a way to do that. If not, it should be easy to subclass it and override the tostring method to allow for the currency pattern to be passed in (unless it's a `sealed` class or something, in which case, gross).

Comment: I have tested `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0C}")]` with the result of `20C`, so.. this doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I finally came with a culture info configuration in my `BaseController`. In that config i have set the value for the `CurrencyPositivePattern` to 3.